# Why MetaModel parameter is null

Tags: java, jpa, metamodel

I have a very simple model class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reach")
public class Reach {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private Long uId;

    @Column(name = "reach_30")
    private Integer reach30;

... getters, setters..
}
```

And here is my meta model

```
@StaticMetamodel(Reach.class)
public class Reach_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Reach, Long> uId;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Reach, Integer> reach30;
}
```

And when i print following

```
    System.out.println("==============="+(Reach_.uId));
    System.out.println("==============="+(Reach_.reach30));
```

I get object value for `uId` **BUT NULL for `reach30`**. Any idea whats going on here.

Thankx

Answer (score -1):

Problem was with eclipse. Needed to clean and restart computer to get it working. But not a problem with code